# ERROR: Out of local stack

Tags: prolog

Hi Every Body i have this problem when i try to run this prolog code "ERROR: Out of local stack"

this is the code

:- redefine_system_predicate(write(_)).
:- redefine_system_predicate(readln(_)).

write(S) :-
    is_list(S) -> format('~s', [S]) ; format('~w', [S]).
write(A,B,C,D) :-
    maplist(write, [A,B,C,D]).
write(A,B,C) :-
    maplist(write, [A,B,C]).
readchar(S) :-
    get(C), atom_codes(S, [C]).
readln(A) :-
    system:readln(L), atomic_list_concat(L,' ',A).

go :-
    write("What is the patient's name? "),
    readln(Patient),
    hypothesis(Patient,Disease),
    write(Patient,"probably has ",Disease,"."),nl.

go :-
    write("Sorry, I don't seem to be able to"),nl,
    write("diagnose the disease."),nl.

symptom(Patient,fever) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a fever (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,rash) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a rash (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,headache) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a headache (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,runny_nose) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a runny_nose (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a conjunctivitis (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,cough) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a cough (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,body_ache) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a body_ache (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,chills) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a chills (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,sore_throat) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a sore_throat (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,sneezing) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a sneezing (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,swollen_glands) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a swollen_glands (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

hypothesis(Patient,measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,cough),
    symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,rash).

hypothesis(Patient,german_measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,rash).

hypothesis(Patient,flu) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,body_ache),
    symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis),
    symptom(Patient,chills),
    symptom(Patient,sore_throat),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,cough).

hypothesis(Patient,common_cold) :-
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,sneezing),
    symptom(Patient,sore_throat),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,chills).

hypothesis(Patient,mumps) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,swollen_glands).

hypothesis(Patient,chicken_pox) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,chills),
    symptom(Patient,body_ache),
    symptom(Patient,rash).

hypothesis(Patient,measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,cough),
    symptom(Patient,sneezing),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose).

response(Reply) :-
    readchar(Reply),
    write(Reply),nl.

any suggestion please ??

Comment: @mbratch: did you tested ? I think that's correct instead. Going to test...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do Solve the problem by using new version of SWI-Prolog and remove write and readln statements the code become as below.

:- redefine_system_predicate(write(_)).
:- redefine_system_predicate(readln(_)).

write(A,B,C,D) :-
    maplist(write, [A,B,C,D]).
write(A,B,C) :-
    maplist(write, [A,B,C]).
readchar(S) :-
    get(C), atom_codes(S, [C]).

go :-
    write("What is the patient\'s name? "),
    readln(Patient),
    hypothesis(Patient,Disease),
    write(Patient,"probably has ",Disease,"."),nl.

go :-
    write("Sorry, I don't seem to be able to"),nl,
    write("diagnose the disease."),nl.

symptom(Patient,fever) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a fever (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,rash) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a rash (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,headache) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a headache (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,runny_nose) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a runny_nose (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a conjunctivitis (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,cough) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a cough (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,body_ache) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a body_ache (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,chills) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a chills (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,sore_throat) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a sore_throat (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,sneezing) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a sneezing (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,swollen_glands) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a swollen_glands (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

hypothesis(Patient,measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,cough),
    symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,rash).

hypothesis(Patient,german_measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,rash).

hypothesis(Patient,flu) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,body_ache),
    symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis),
    symptom(Patient,chills),
    symptom(Patient,sore_throat),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,cough).

hypothesis(Patient,common_cold) :-
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,sneezing),
    symptom(Patient,sore_throat),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,chills).

hypothesis(Patient,mumps) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,swollen_glands).

hypothesis(Patient,chicken_pox) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,chills),
    symptom(Patient,body_ache),
    symptom(Patient,rash).

hypothesis(Patient,measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,cough),
    symptom(Patient,sneezing),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose).

response(Reply) :-
    readchar(Reply),
    write(Reply),nl.

Comment: Why redefine `write/1` and `readln/1`? Also, you could do a single `write_words(W) :- maplist(write, W).` and call it by, for example, `write_words(["Does ", Patient, " have chills (y/n) ?"])`. That way, you don't need a separate predicate for each different number of parameters.

Comment: didnt work !!! its work only for first and second statements !!! i dont know why !!! o.O

Comment: sorry I meant single quotes: `write_words(['Does ', Patient, ' have chills (y/n) ?']).` Single quotes are for strings.

Answer (score 2):

You have a loop here:

```
readln(A) :- system:readln(L), atomic_list_concat(L,' ',A).
```

test

```
1 ?- [user].
|: :- redefine_system_predicate(readln(_)).
|: readln(A) :- system:readln(L), atomic_list_concat(L,' ',A).
% user://1 compiled 0.03 sec, 2 clauses
true.

2 ?- readln(X).
ERROR: Out of local stack
3 ?-
```

Another problem, but not leading to stackoverflow...
If you use a recent SWI-Prolog (version >= 7.0), beware of your test about a string 'type': double quoted literals are no longer lists.

```
?- is_list("123").
false.
```

Comment: @mbratch: write performs an arity reduction, then recursion has first clause as base case

Answer (score 1):

"Out of local stack" means that you have no memory left to compute the results, due to some of these reasons:

- Usually there's an infinite loop somewhere. Missing base case in recursive loop.
- Lists you are working with are too big.
- There's a lot of backtracking and the interpreter can't handle it.

I think first one applies here `readln(A) :- system:readln(L), atomic_list_concat(L,' ',A).`

Anyway, if you need more memory, you can expand the stacks with `set_prolog_stack/2` in SWI-Prolog.

Comment: No stack growing will amend that bug!

Comment: Definitely not. Solve the loop.